# Chromatic Polynomial when two disjoint graphs are joined at $2$ distinct points

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings, chromatic-polynomial

Consider a graph with chromatic polynomial $P(x)$ joined to a clique of order $k$ in two distinct points (joining here just means interesection of points). Then, what is the chromatic polynomial of the new graph obtained by this joining?

Specifically, I think it is of the form $\frac{P(x)\cdot x_{(k)}\cdot (x-2)}{x(x-1)^2}$, where $x_{(k)}$ denotes the falling factorial. This is the form that was obtained when I experimented with some low order cliques. Is this true in general? If the two graphs share one single point or a clique in between them, then the resulting chromatic polynomial of the graph is well known. But, there is no formula in the above case. Though the deletion-contraction formula would give the appropriate polynomial, but is there a known formula beforehand? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There can be no formula of that nature because it must depend on which two vertices are used for attaching the clique. For example if you just take a 6-cycle and connect two vertices with an edge (which is joining a 2-clique to a graph) then you can make a bipartite graph by joining opposite vertices or a non-bipartite graph by joining non-opposite vertices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Gordon Royle remarked, it may depend on the choice of vertices to attach to the clique.

Let $G$ be your original graph, and $a$ and $b$ your two points.
If If $x \ge k$, an $x$-colouring of your new graph can be obtained by taking an $x$-colouring of $G$ in which $a$ and $b$ have different colours, and then colouring the remaining $k-2$ vertices of the $k$-clique using the $x-2$ colours not used for $a$ and $b$.  Thus the number of such colourings is $(x-2)!/(x-k)!$ times the number $\widetilde{P}(x)$ of $x$-colourings of $G$ in which $a$ and $b$ have different colours.
If $a$ and $b$ are adjacent in $G$, then $\widetilde{P} = P$.  If they are not adjacent, then $\widetilde{P}(x) = P(x)- P_{G_{a=b}}(x)$, where $P_{G_{a=b}}(x)$ is the chromatic polynomial of the graph $G_{a=b}$ obtained from $G$ by identifying $a$ with $b$.

Comment: so the case when $a$ and $b$ are not adjacent is just the deletion-contraction method restated

Comment: so suppose the $2$ vertices are increased to $3$ or more vertices, then I think we have to use inclusion-exclusion principle, right?